# JasperReports Static Text bold not working with program

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a `Static Text` field set as bold in jasper studio. It is working as expected while exporting as PDF from studio. The same jrxml file when used in java program and pdf gets generated, the static text is not displayed as bold but plain text. Using jasperreports-6.20.6.jar.

```
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="d20e2fa5-05f7-481f-a71e-694e3951e368">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SENT TO:]]></text>
            </staticText>
```

Exported as below.

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"filename.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

jasperreports-fonts jar(dependency) is required to for bold to take effect. Just adding the dependency solved the issue.